# Adding to list of arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist, nested, addition

I am trying to add the following 2 which are stored in tempEdges:

> 1. [RoyalElephant, IS-A, Elephant]
> 2. [RoyalElephant, IS-NOT-A, Gray]

although i only want the last 2 elements of each arraylist to be added to the 2 arraylists in copiedPaths.

The arraylists are:

```
            public static List<ArrayList<String>> copiedPaths = new ArrayList<>();
            public static List<ArrayList<String>> tempEdges = new ArrayList<>();
```

And the dis-functional code is:

```
            copiedPaths.get(0).add(tempEdges.get(0).get(1));
            copiedPaths.get(0).add(tempEdges.get(0).get(2));
            copiedPaths.get(1).add(tempEdges.get(1).get(1));
            copiedPaths.get(1).add(tempEdges.get(1).get(2));
```

This is not working as intended as both arrays are being added with **IS-NOT-A**, Gray instead of one having **IS-A**, Elephant and the other having **IS-NOT-A**, Gray

Comment: I know, that is not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> copiedPaths = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tempEdges = new ArrayList<>();


    tempEdges.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("RoyalElephant", "IS-A", "Elephant")));
    tempEdges.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("RoyalElephant", "IS-NOT-A", "Gray")));

    copiedPaths.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tempEdges.get(0).get(1),tempEdges.get(0).get(2))));
    copiedPaths.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tempEdges.get(1).get(1),tempEdges.get(1).get(2))));


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copiedPaths.get(0).toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copiedPaths.get(1).toArray()));
```

---

Output:-

[IS-A, Elephant]

[IS-NOT-A, Gray]

Answer (score 1):

Java 9+ solution:

```
List<List<String>> tempEdges = List.of(List.of("RoyalElephant", "IS-A", "Elephant"),
                                       List.of("RoyalElephant", "IS-NOT-A", "Gray"));

List<List<String>> copiedPaths = tempEdges.stream()
        .map(list -> list.subList(1, list.size()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(tempEdges);
System.out.println(copiedPaths);
```

For Java 8+, use `Arrays.asList` instead of `List.of`.

For Java 7+, use:

```
List<List<String>> tempEdges = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("RoyalElephant", "IS-A", "Elephant"),
                                             Arrays.asList("RoyalElephant", "IS-NOT-A", "Gray"));

List<List<String>> copiedPaths = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<String> list : tempEdges)
    copiedPaths.add(list.subList(1, list.size()));

System.out.println(tempEdges);
System.out.println(copiedPaths);
```

*Output*

```
[[RoyalElephant, IS-A, Elephant], [RoyalElephant, IS-NOT-A, Gray]]
[[IS-A, Elephant], [IS-NOT-A, Gray]]
```

Note that `subList` creates a view of the underlying list. If the original `tempEdges` lists can change, you need to create a copy, i.e. change

```
list.subList(1, list.size())
```

to

```
new ArrayList<>(list.subList(1, list.size()))
```

Comment: Thanks, why didn't using the .get() and .add() not work for me though?

Comment: @MrMosby Because you never created the inner lists in `copiedPaths`.